# why is angular number pipe not displaying if number has a leading zero?

Tags: angular, typescript

Why does `number pipe` not display when the value has a leading zero when I use it like below?

0.35 won't display in UI.
3.5 will display.

```html
<!-- numbVal = 0.35 -->

<!-- output '' -->
<div>
 {{numbVal | number }}
</div>

<!-- output '' -->
<div>
 {{numbVal | number:'3.1-5' }}
</div>



<!-- numbVal = 3.5 -->

<!-- output '3.5' -->
<div>
 {{numbVal | number }}
</div>

<!-- output '003.5' -->
<div>
 {{numbVal | number:'3.1-5' }}
</div>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-16btuo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. Post a complete minimal example as a stackblitz that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I tired the same code snippet and it works fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tlm2np. Do you have a customized number pipe?

Comment: okay. weird. I closed everything down and reopened (vscode, chrome) and it's working. should this be closed? sorry.

Comment: @ironman, yes, I think it's best to delete this question unless you can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{{numbVal | number:'1.1-5' }}
```

It will get it to display 0.35.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of number pipe:

```
{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}
```

So your example of `'3.1-5'` means:

A minimum of 3 digit will be shown before decimal point
It will show at least 1 digits after decimal point
But not more than 5 digits

Sample

```
{{0.351255 | number:'3.1-5' }}  //000.35126

 {{10 | number:'3.1-5' }}  //010.0

 {{0.35 | number:'1.1-2' }} //0.35
```

With your requirement, you can use `{{ 0.35 | number:'1.1-2' }}`

More at https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe